# PHP integrating Stripe

Tags: php

[RootProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJYyx.jpg)[image]

I got a PHP fatal error because I'm sure it's because I don't know how line #4 works: (please also see picture attached for details). Config.php script is below: (to be honest, I copied this from open source)

Config.php:

```
session_start();
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "class-db.php";
use Omnipay\Omnipay;        
define('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY', 'pk_test_51MZE');
define('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY', 'sk_test_51MZE3g1nq');
define('RETURN_URL’, orange.fruit.com/confirm.php');
define('PAYMENT_CURRENCY', 'USD');
$gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe\PaymentIntents');
$gateway->setApiK`ey(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```

I tried to learn "namespace" and "use", but still failed to fix my Config.php script.

Clarification:

In my cPanel directory (I called this “root” directory) is a list of folders. And two of those folders are: 1. vendor folder – which has omnipay, which in turn has stripe. 2. a project folder named “orange.fruit.com”. (not real name of course to maintain anonymity for now, but shouldn’t affect the structure of the question here).

Now, separately, the “root of the project folder” (if you will) contains several php scripts that I copied from open source, including the Config.php script file. These scripts are for the purpose of connecting to Stripe, as you know. Link to open source:

artisansweb.net/guide-stripe-integration-website-php

So in my opinion, I believe I got everything in place to run the Config.php. But when I run Config.php, I get the fatal error “cannot find class” as described above.

I tried to learn about “namespace” and “use”, and then edited Config.php with some variations, but to no avail.

So now, I’m stuck as a door nail. Could you please help me resolve? I think GetSet had somethig in mind, so hoping GetSet or anyone can provide support.

Thank you very much!

Comment: A 500/Internal server error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: The error is this (exactly this, except for me changing 3 words to basket/orange/fruit):  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Omnipay\Omnipay" not found in /home/basket/orange.fruit.com/config.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/basket/orange.fruit.com/config.php on line 15

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `Omnipay\Omnipay` and not `Omnipay\Stripe`? You have a Stripe and Paypal folder under Ominpay, though I'm not sure what's in `common`. Which library are you using?

Comment: Just changed to Ominpay\Stripe, and now the error is this:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Omnipay" not found in...

Comment: Btw, here is the open source website where I got the Config.php script:  
https://artisansweb.net/guide-stripe-integration-website-php/

Comment: "to be honest, I copied this from open source" ... You probably need/forgot to install the Omipay php library. Refer to their official docs, wherever they may reside.

Comment: @GetSet that might be the case, but then the `vendor`  folder would not contain the `omnipay` folder

Comment: @Student whats the url that you copied the codebase from? I'd like to have a look at some of the files as it might help in debugging this.

Comment: @GetSet I got the Config.php script at this site: artisansweb.net/guide-stripe-integration-website-php. As far as installing composer and then omnipay, it was done correctly according to my host server support team, as they said the omnipay install is fine in the support ticket.

Comment: @Student You say "Root has vendor/company". Where is the "project" folder in relation to the "vendor" folder? Let's take the fatal error literally (as we have to) "class not found" due to a path issue. How do you usually access libraries in your root folder?

Comment: @GetSet - Ah, yes great question... and maybe this is where I have errored.  I added a screenshot, please click on RootProject above to see my root and project folder details at cPanel. Thank you, sir, so much for helping me to resolve this!

Comment: Please share all details **in text form**, not hidden in images

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question**, not to the comment section, and not hidden in images